# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to open many json files and write them to one csv file I wrote a code that worked for reading one file but when I wanted to append all files together I received traceback.

My code is

```py
path_to_json = r'\path'
json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')]
json_text_list = []
for index, js in enumerate(json_files):
    with open(os.path.join(path_to_json, js), encoding="utf8") as json_file:
        json_text_list.append(json.load(json_file))
        json_text = json.load(json_file)
```

Error:

```
File "C:\Users\and\Desktop\t.py", line 18, in <module>
    json_text = json.load(json_file)
  File "C:\Users\and\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\and\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\and\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\and\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to open the file in read mode, and call the `.read()` method on the the file handler to actually get the contents as a string that can be parsed by json.

That is why we use `json.loads()`

Here is the solution -

```
import os
import json

path_to_json = r'\path'
json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir(path_to_json) if pos_json.endswith('.json')] 
json_text_list = [] 
for index, js in enumerate(json_files): 
    with open(os.path.join(path_to_json, js), 'r') as json_file:
        json_data = json.loads(json_file.read())
        json_text_list.append(json_data)
```

Comment: Hi @shreyashag I tried this code but got the following error.....SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Comment: @RIGCode, my bad. Have edited the post with the fix.

Comment: thank you so much for the quick answer.  it has thrown another error it drives me crazy.   with open(os.path.join(path_to_json, js), "utf8", 'r') as json_file:
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

Comment: @RIGCode Have fixed it and verified that the code is now working. The 'r' mode needed to be before the charset. If you need charset, add encoding="utf8" as a parameter as the last parameter for open.

Comment: it worked. but somwhow the next line of code gives an error. result = json_normalize(json_text, errors='ignore')
in json_normalize
    if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data):

Comment: @RIGCode, this is not part of your original question. Please mark the solution as correct.

If you need a solution to the complete answer, please post the question with the complete code.